# Enzyme testing a click with an event as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

'I am trying to test out this code using enzyme. I want to simulate a click but i get an error "Reference Error, Event is not defined". How do i get past that? Do i need to mock the function?'

```
const handleClick = (event : any) => {
  setAnchorEl(event.target);
  setOpen(true);
};
<IconButton onClick={() => handleClick(event)}>
  <DeleteIcon className={classes.threeDotsIcon}/>
</IconButton>
```

I tried simulating the click like this but it gives me an error, event is not defined.

'''

```
let wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store1}><MyComponent{...mockProps} /></Provider>);
let button = wrapper.findWhere(elem => elem.name() === 'IconButton');
button.simulate('click');'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass the event to `handleClick` event handler, `onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}`. And you need to pass a simulated click event object like this `button.simulate('click', { target: 'whatever' })`

Comment: I can't pass the event to the IconButton, It gives me this error - "Type '(event: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)"